Does this correctly show that there is an affine transformation that takes a circle in the plane (arbitrarily close) to a parabola?
I believe this is essentially just a way to show that there is an anisotropic scaling of a circle that produces an ellipse arbitrarily close to a parabola.
Let $u \in [0,2\pi)$, $R \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$
Let $$\Phi:\mathbb{R^2}\times [0,\frac{\pi}{4}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R^2}$$ be given by $$\Phi(x,y,t)=\left(\frac{1+\tan(t+\frac{\pi}{4})}{2\sqrt{\tan(t+\frac{\pi}{4})}}x,\frac{1+\tan(t+\frac{\pi}{4})}{2}y\right)$$
If we choose some $t_1 \in [0,\frac{\pi}{4})$ then the map $\Phi(x,y,t_1)$ is just an anisotropic scaling of the $xy$-plane.
If we choose some $t_2 \in [0,\frac{\pi}{4})$ arbitrarily close to $\frac{\pi}{4}$, then $$\Phi(R\cos(u),R+R\sin(u),t_2)$$ comes arbitrarily close to parametrizing the parabola $y=\frac{x^2}{R}$, as can be seen in my simulation
Thus, the affine transformation $$\begin{bmatrix} \frac{1+\tan(t_2+\frac{\pi}{4})}{2\sqrt{\tan(t_2+\frac{\pi}{4})}} & 0 \\\ 0 & \frac{1+\tan(t_2+\frac{\pi}{4})}{2}\end{bmatrix}$$ comes arbitrarily close to taking the circle given by $x^2+(y-R)^2=R^2$ to the parabola $y=\frac{x^2}{R}$
